# Get MAX value from one column and MIN from another column

Tags: mysql

I've been building a game based on Candy Crush. The Score table has the three following columns:

```
stage_level_id                        | value | moves
------------------------------------------------------
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53  | 35000 | 350
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53  | 35000 | 500
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54  | 15000 | 125
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54  | 13500 | 100
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55  | 12500 | 350
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55  | 7500  | 25
```

I need to get the top Score grouped by `stage_level_id`. If an `stage_level_id` have the same `Value` (as the one ending with 53), it must return the row with the smallest number of `Moves`.

I'm trying the following but it's not working as expected:

```
SELECT a.stage_level_id, MAX(a.value) as max_value, a.moves
FROM scores a
LEFT JOIN scores b ON (
  a.stage_level_id = b.stage_level_id
)
RIGHT JOIN scores c ON (
  c.moves = ( SELECT MIN(moves) as moves FROM scores WHERE c.stage_level_id =         a.stage_level_id )
)
WHERE a.player_id = 1475332386040815
GROUP BY a.stage_level_id
```

The expected result is:

```
stage_level_id                        | value | moves
------------------------------------------------------
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53  | 35000 | 350
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54  | 15000 | 125
9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55  | 12500 | 350
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Are there any other columns in that table? Such as a unique ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt wasn't that far off.  You were missing a necessary part of the first JOIN ... ON clause though, and the second JOIN isn't necessary.

```
SELECT tbl1.stage_level_id, tbl1.max_value, MIN(s.moves) AS moves
FROM 
(
  SELECT stage_level_id, MAX(value) AS max_value
  FROM scores
  GROUP BY stage_level_id
) tbl1
LEFT JOIN scores s ON tbl1.stage_level_id = s.stage_level_id AND tbl1.max_value = s.value
GROUP BY stage_level_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55a40f/25)

Comment: Are you sure op isn't just looking for your derived table?

Comment: @FuzzyTree, No surely not .. That was the answer I given at first :)

Comment: the `MIN(moves) AS moves` in the sub query is unnecessary and potentially confusing, see my answer

Comment: @Rahul ah ok, seems op wants min moves grouped by (stage_id,max_score)

Comment: +1 This was the first query to produce the correct results. If you remove the superfluous MIN(moves), it will become identical to mine & I will delete my answer.

Comment: I'm confused if I approve your solution or the one posted by @Mr.Mindor, because they're almost identical.

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves you should accept Patrick's answer as it was posted  almost 20 minutes earlier than Mr. Mindor's :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I'll do it right after the removal of `MIN(moves) AS moves`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the minimum number of moves for each (stage_id,max score) group using `NOT EXISTS`

```
select stage_level_id, max(value), min(moves)
from scores s1
where not exists (
    select 1 from scores s2
    where s2.stage_level_id = s1.stage_level_id
    and s2.value > s1.value
)
group by stage_level_id;
```

The `not exists` part limits the results to only those rows that have the maximum score within each group (in other words no other row with a higher score within the group exists).

This query can take advantage of a composite index on `(stage_id,value)`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88ee6/8

Comment: this is interesting, but how does it compare performance wise to joining against a sub query selecting the max score for a stage?

Comment: also, I assume you want `from scores s1` as that is how you refer to it in the sub query

Comment: @Mr.Mindor with the index it seems to outperform joining against sub query - query plan for both http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88ee6/7

Comment: this honestly should be the accepted answer as exists is one of the fastest ways to execute a mysql query with the correct indexes

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this can be done simply by one `select` with a `left join` and a `group by`:

```
select s1.stage_level_id, s1.score, min(s1.moves) as moves
from scores s1
  left join scores s2
    on s2.stage_level_id = s1.stage_level_id
    and s2.score > s1.score
where s2.score IS NULL
group by s1.stage_level_id;
```

The `left join` gives:

```
| s1                                                   | s2                                                     |
|--------------------------------------|-------|-------|--------------------------------------|--------|--------|
| stage_level_id                       | score | moves | stage_level_id                       | score  | moves  |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53 | 35000 | 350   | (null)                               | (null) | (null) |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53 | 35000 | 500   | (null)                               | (null) | (null) |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54 | 15000 | 125   | (null)                               | (null) | (null) |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54 | 13500 | 100   | 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54 | 15000  | 125    |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55 | 7500  | 25    | 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55 | 12500  | 350    |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55 | 12500 | 350   | (null)                               | (null) | (null) |
```

The `where` clause selects the rows that contain the highest score(s) per `stage_level_id`:

```
| s1                                                   | s2                               |
|--------------------------------------|-------|-------|----------------|--------|--------|
| stage_level_id                       | score | moves | stage_level_id | score  | moves  |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53 | 35000 | 350   | (null)         | (null) | (null) |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53 | 35000 | 500   | (null)         | (null) | (null) |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54 | 15000 | 125   | (null)         | (null) | (null) |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55 | 12500 | 350   | (null)         | (null) | (null) |
```

so that we can run `min(s1.moves)` on each `stage_level_id` group formulated by `group by` to get the final result:

```
| s1                                                   | s2                               |
|--------------------------------------|-------|-------|----------------|--------|--------|
| stage_level_id                       | score | moves | stage_level_id | score  | moves  |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53 | 35000 | 350   | (null)         | (null) | (null) |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54 | 15000 | 125   | (null)         | (null) | (null) |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55 | 12500 | 350   | (null)         | (null) | (null) |
```

or

```
| stage_level_id                       | score | moves |
|--------------------------------------|-------|-------|
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b53 | 35000 | 350   |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b54 | 15000 | 125   |
| 9f7678f0-fc8f-11e3-a398-b2227cce2b55 | 12500 | 350   |
```

Test it out at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50ed8/6/0.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I misunderstood the question but isnt it as simple as this:

```
SELECT column1, max(column2), IF(column1 like "%53", min(column3), max(column3))
FROM test
GROUP BY column1
;
```

Check this out, [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b203/2)